# Does negative charge move from lower potential to higher potential?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, potential-energy

[image]

This image implies that charge flows from a higher potential to lower potential….but if we attack a battery to a circuit then the current will flow from lower potential (positive terminal) to higher potential (negative terminal) then tell me what is correct?

Comment: just a little nitpick , we say that the positive terminal is higher potential(as there is a net positive charge and we define potential based on the work needed for a unit positive charge to move it from infinity) and negative terminal is lower potential , The conventional current(as defined in the olden days) is defined to be from positive to negative where actually electrons flow from negative to positive

Comment: Who said you that there is a positive charge at positive terminal……there is just defeciency of electrons as compared to negative terminal.

Comment: yes that's why there is a net positive charge felt at the positive potential , sorry If my words were misleading @Physics student now I have edited it to make it more clear

Answer (score -1):

It is best to speak of a potential difference and yes, useful work can only occur when a medium flows freely and thus from a higher to a lower potential.

For electrons, this means that electrons move from a place with an excess of electrons (higher potential) to a place with a shortage of electrons (lower potential).

In an ionic solution, this also means that ions move in the opposite direction. The potential difference for ions is therefore opposite to that for electrons.